# Gradle versionName and versionCode not working after 3.0 update

Tags: android, build.gradle

```
    flavorDimensions "app"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            resValue "string", "base_url", "http://mydevurl/"
            dimension "app"
        }
        prod {
            resValue "string", "base_url", "http://myprodurl/"
            dimension "app"
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor
        def versionName
        if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
            versionName = "debug_0.1.1"
        }else{
            versionName = "0.1.1"
        }
        flavor.versionName = versionName
        flavor.versionCode = 50
    }
```

Above gradle setup was working fine till Gradle 3.0 update. Couldn't find anything related in the website referred. How to manage this dynamic version control based on this new `flavorDimension` change?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can dynamically set the versionCode and versionName with the 3.0 Android gradle plugin by using VariantOutput.setVersionCodeOverride() and VariantOutput.setVersionNameOverride().

For your project, this would look something like:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor
    def versionName
    if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
        versionName = "debug_0.1.1"
    }else{
        versionName = "0.1.1"
    }
    flavor.versionName = versionName
    flavor.versionCode = 50
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        output.setVersionNameOverride(versionName)
        output.setVersionCodeOverride(50)
    }       
}
```

reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63785806#comment6

Comment: Thanks for the update and getting this issue in notice. I updated the answer and removed few unnecessary part of the code.